# Best Practices for Dummy Values in Coq

Tags: coq

I find that I'm frequently writing code like this:

```
  Fixpoint get_fresh w (Γ : Ctx) : Pat w * Ctx:= 
  match w with
  ... 
  | w1 ⊗ w2 => let (p1, Γ1) := get_fresh w1 Γ in
              match Γ ⋓ Γ1 with
              | None  => (dummy_pat _, dummy_ctx)
              | Some Γ' => (p1,Γ')
  end.
```

Where the `None` branch will never be entered. (Here, it's impossible to enter the branch, sometimes we will never enter the branch on an appropriate input.)

What's the best way to implement the dummy values that should never be returned?

An easy approach is to simply declare

```
Parameter dummy_pat : forall W, Pat W.
Parameter dummy_ctx : Ctx.
```

But that sounds seems like bad practice - for all the user knows `Ctx` and `Pat W` might have no inhabitants. (This is especially true for dependent types like `Pat W`.)

I could give simple definitions for `dummy_pat` and `dummy_ctx` but I don't want users reasoning about this branch. I could declare `dummy_pat` and `dummy_ctx` opaque, but opacity is disturbingly easy to reverse.

Finally, I guess I could declare these as the a projection from a sigma type, but it seems like that would be confusing, and I'm not sure it addresses the problem of reasoning about that case.

(Note that I don't want to intrinsically prove that these branches are inaccessible, using `Program` or otherwise. I find these functions very difficult to write and to use.)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The following way of declaring a module may have better opaqueness guarantees (but if I'm wrong I'd be very interested to know!):

```
Module Type DummySig.
Parameter dummy_pat : forall W, Pat W.
Parameter dummy_ctx : Ctx.
End DummySig.

Module Import Dummy : DummySig.
Definition dummy_pat := (* some simple definition *)
Definition dummy_ctx := (* some simple definition *)
End Dummy.
```

#### Explanation

`Module Import Dummy : DummySig.` is short for `Module Dummy : DummySig` followed by `Import Dummy.` after the closing `End Dummy.` command.

`Module Dummy : DummySig.` declares a module with module type (or *signature*) `DummySig`, and also *seals* the module so that only the information declared in `DummySig` is visible about this `Dummy` module.

This is a strong abstraction boundary that hides all of the implementation details. In particular, a `Parameter` in `DummySig` makes a definition opaque in `Dummy`, and identifiers defined in `Dummy` that do not appear in `DummySig` are not visible at all from outside the module.

As far as I can tell, **this opaqueness is irreversible**, which is the key point here.

For comparison, the two other ways of declaring modules are:

- `Module M.` exposes everything in the module `M`, so it is mostly a kind of namespacing.
- `Module M <: MSig.`, also exposes everything in `M`, while checking that it implements the signature `MSig` (defined via `Module Type MSig.`), without the "sealing" aspect of `Module M : Sig.`.

---

#### Other proposed solutions

You can also turn the dummies into actual parameters, either via a module functor...

```
Module MyProject (Dummy : DummySig).
Import Dummy.

...
```

or a section; to avoid having to pass dummies around, a type class may be useful.

```
Class Dummy (A : Type) := { dummy : A }.

Section Dummies.
Context `{forall W, Dummy (Pat W)}.
Context `{Dummy Ctx}.

...
```

At the end of the day I wonder whether it is really bad that users can reason about inaccessible branches.

Comment: It's not clear to me how this addresses the issue.

In `Module Import Dummy` what goes in the ellipses after `Definition dummy_pat`?

Comment: Any simple definition can go in the ellipses. This was meant to address the point about opacity being easy to reverse: `Module Dummy : DummySig` makes the definitions in the module opaque in an irreversible way, does it not? Similarly, the module functor approach and the section are alternative ways to ensure the dummies are opaque via parametricity.

Comment: I don't have a particularly good understanding of the module system, and the documentation isn't helping me much here. Why is it that first defining a `Module Type` and then writing a module that has that module type ensures opacity, while simply writing a module doesn't?

Comment: I added a bit of an explanation in the first part of my answer, tell me if anything is still unclear!

Comment: Is there any reason to use modules here?  You get the same opaqueness with Qed.

Comment: Oh, yours sounds like a better idea.